# How to add contacts which were in older journey version into the new active version of journey :sfmc

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sfmc-business-unit

We have a journey for which data is coming from website.
We created journey version 1 so that all the contacts which were get added inside the DE will get the emails.
Now we need to update our journey and add some more emails in version 2.
So my question is, how can we make sure that the contacts which were in older version will get added to the new or active version when they finished the older  version.
Note we already updating date and time of each email send back into DE in older version but we need to make sure that the contacts should enter in newer version once they finished the execution in older version.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Is anyone have any idea about how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. clone the journey and add the extra email
2. target a new DE from the website as entry for the new journey (or you risk to target the existing journey)
3. create with SQL a tracking DE where you can check if the records have received the last email of the other journey, if so add them to the DE
4. Include with update the new DE with the old entry records using SQL to allow them to re-enter if they received the last email
5. have a decision split checking the DE populated with SQL in step 3 to double check if they have received the last email in the original journey
6. as part of your journey use the update contact activity to track steps as it would be easier to amend the journey in the future
7. check the entry settings - the reason why I suggest you to create a separate journey is that in order to retrigger the same journey you need to allow all records in the DE to be evaluated and allow re-entry.